# Is it normal to have a file called "shadow-" in the /etc directory?

Tags: security, etc, shadow

I am noticing a lot of weird files appearing in my router and on my various filesystems. Files in weird places or files that have to do with security with a - sign after them.

If I do `ls -l /etc/shadow*`, this is what I see.

```
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1163 Aug  9 15:48 shadow
-rw------- 1 root root   1163 Aug  8 21:11 shadow-
```

Does that look normal? What is the 2nd shadow file used for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These files are perfectly normal.

From the [shadow(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) manual page:

> `/etc/shadow-`
>   Backup file for `/etc/shadow`.

You may similarly see `/etc/passwd-`, `/etc/group-` and `/etc/gshadow-`.

These backup files are created all the tools in the Linux user database utility suite ([shadow](http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/)): both interactive tools such as [`vipw`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vipw) and automated tools such as `passwd`, `useradd`, etc. They let you easily revert the last change to the user database.

Comment: But I didn't use vipw, and no one else is supposed to know the root password but me. So isn't this suspicious?

Comment: @awakeFromNib Diff them - see if you recognize the change. Apparently some of the other account modification tools do it too.

Comment: @awakeFromNib It would be surprising not to see this file, unless you manually removed it recently. It would mean you never ever added or removed an account or changed a password since your initial system installation. Installing some packages that provide daemons creates a user to run the daemon, so this file can be created even if you didn't directly manipulate accounts.